# Latex make comic book page

Tags: latex

I want to make a comic book of 60 pages. I only need to design 2 kinds  of page, one for odd number of pages and another for even number of pages. I designed these 2 kind of layout with adove illustrator, but but inserting comic pictures very tedious and placing exact places are quite difficult.

I think of Latex, but I have not much experiences with it. could anyone tell me how to design comic pages with latex. each page only have 4 picture with a title,quite simple. I want to know how to start such things.

I want to able to draw tables and place pictures at exact positions. is there any way to design layout of pages with latex?

Thanks in advance 
:)

Comment: This might be better suited to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ (but make sure you read their question guidelines first and make sure you follow them!)

Comment: TeX was created for typesetting text and mathemathics. While it can handle pictures, that was never the primary purpose.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199960/comic-book-or-graphic-novel-style-panels-in-latex